Problem in solving four ordinary differential equations in Mathematica
I have the following set of four ordinary differential equations:
  ODEs = {D[r00[t], t] == -2*g*r00[t] - I*((-h21[t])*r01[t] + h12[t]*r10[t]), 
          D[r01[t], t] == (-g)*r01[t] - I*((-h12[t])*r00[t] + h11[t]*r01[t] - 
       h22[t]*r01[t] + h12[t]*r11[t]), D[r10[t], t] == 
    (-g)*r10[t] - I*(h21[t]*r00[t] - h11[t]*r10[t] + h22[t]*r10[t] - 
       h21[t]*r11[t]), D[r11[t], t] == 2*g*r00[t] - 
     I*(h21[t]*r01[t] - h12[t]*r10[t])}

Here g is a real constant. Now I want to solve these equations with general initial conditions. I tried the following but it doesn't work:
DSolve[ODEs, {r00[t], r01[t], r10[t], r11[t]}, t]

It just gives the output
     DSolve[{Derivative[1][r00][t] == -2*g*r00[t] - 
         I*((-h21[t])*r01[t] + h12[t]*r10[t]), Derivative[1][r01][t] == 
        (-g)*r01[t] - I*((-h12[t])*r00[t] + h11[t]*r01[t] - h22[t]*r01[t] + 
           h12[t]*r11[t]), Derivative[1][r10][t] == 
        (-g)*r10[t] - I*(h21[t]*r00[t] - h11[t]*r10[t] + h22[t]*r10[t] - 
           h21[t]*r11[t]), Derivative[1][r11][t] == 
        2*g*r00[t] - I*(h21[t]*r01[t] - h12[

t]*r10[t])}, 
  {r00[t], r01[t], r10[t], r11[t]}, t]


So the h??[t] are undefined coefficients?

h[t] are are some general time dependent coefficients.

Well, DSolve won't solve the simpler general system, DSolve[  {x'[t] == a[t] x[t] + b[t] y[t],   y'[t] == c[t] x[t] + d[t] y[t]},  {x, y}, t]. I don't know of an approach that gives a symbolic solution to such a general system, even though it's linear.

Coupled linear differential equations of the form d/dt =  .  can be solved by diagonalising .

To add to my previous comment, diagonalisation will DEcouple the differential equations, but successfully solving (in closed symbolic form) these decoupled equations will depend on their coefficients - dependent on the h??[t] - having a "nice" time dependence.

@Stephen Luttrell, Could you elaborate on this please?

What @Stephen said doesn't quite sound like the following, but the following is how I understand the general situation: ${\bf x}'(t)=A(t),{\bf x}(t) \Rightarrow {\bf x}={\bf x}0\exp\left(\int{t_0}^t A(\tau);d\tau\right)$ is a solution, provided $A(t)$ commutes with its integral. (If the integral of $A(t)$ is also diagonalizable, exponential is easy to compute.)  But commutativity does not hold for, say, A[t] = {{t, 1}, {1, 0}}.  It seems unlikely that your general system would satisfy the commutativity condition. Why do you think your system might have a symbolic general solution?

I was thinking of (a generalisation of) this: Solution by Diagonalization
